# comparison between pointers

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, deque

I am implementing a dequeue in c via arrays. left and right are pointers which point to the leftmost and rightmost elements of the dequeue. The show() function recieves the left and right pointers. When i try the following in void show(int *l,int *r), the function produces wrong output-

```
int *t;
for(t=l;t<r;t++);
    {
        printf("%d-->",*t);
    }
        printf("%d\n",*t);
```

But when i try this it works-

```
for(t=l,i=0;i<r-l;i++,t++)
        printf("%d-->",(*t));
        printf("%d\n",*r);
```

Obviously comparison between pointers in the first code is not working, even though they point to members of the same array, Why is this hapening?

Edit- Here is the whole function

```
void show(int *l,int *r)
{
    if(l==r && r==NULL)
    {
        printf("underflow\n");
    }
    else
    {

        int *t,i;
        for(t=l;t!=r;t++);
        {
                printf("%d-->",*t);
        }
        printf("%d\n",*r);

/*      for(t=l,i=0;i<r-l;i++,t++)
            printf("%d-->",(*t));
        printf("%d\n",*r);*/
    }
}
```

The commented out region is not working in show(). 
Question closed, silly error!!!

Comment: @NiklasB.: Given the left and right pointers, it sounds like he's doing a circular buffer.

Comment: @Jerry: Yeah, I guess that makes sense.

Comment: I don't see `left` or `right`, only `l` and `r`. It'd help if you show the entire function.

Comment: Caleb: "left and right pointers", quote from the question. Not that it was anywhere near clear, of course.

Comment: from main(), i m making a call to show() like show(left,right); thus l and r are formal arguments, should i post the whole code?

Comment: What is the expected and wrong output? What are the actual values of `l` and `r`?

Comment: @ksb If `left` and `right` are important to the question, you should show them in code. If not, leave them out of the question. Show the entire `show()` function. If the output is wrong, either tell us how it differs from the expected result or show us an example.

Comment: Off the cuff, this makes me wonder why you're not using ptrdiff_t

Comment: Please show your pushl or pushr function, it seems you're "passing by reference" strangely. I am using pointer arithmetic in a loop fine that looks just like what you're trying to do

Comment: By the way, if you want, you can do if ((ch=popl(&left,&right))==INT_MIN) ... I think it is easier to read, but I am odd like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(t=l;t!=r;t++);
```

See the semicolon there? Remove it. As is, the loop increments `t` until `r` is reached without doing anything, then the value pointed to be `t` (now `r`) is printed, followed by "-->", and then the value pointed to by `r`.

Answer (score 0):

Edited** Your setting a point to address one here `for(t=l;t<r;t++);` try derefercing t in the for loop to use as the int varible you desire (what you did with i)

Comment: That's the intention, OP doesn't want the "-->" after the last element.

Comment: Initially I though that deque is comprised of several separate memory blocks, so they could be allocated in different order (I'm talking about memory layout here). Will remove my original answer as it seems we are dealing with one and only block